# pre-populate a web form based with PHP Variables that are based on user selection

Tags: php

I have a web form that is generated from a $_GET function.

I would like to populate some input fields in this web form from the data that was passed using PHP.

Any ideas how I could go about doing this?

Thanks

### Here is the PHP (which is successfully passed the variables from the row that the user selected, phew!)

```
<html>
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('
        SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
          a_aif.fee_source_id,
          a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
          a_aif.document_filing_date
        FROM  a_aif
        WHERE a_aif.fee_source_id = :id');
    $sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<form action="submit_data.php" method="get" autocomplete="on">

<?php
    echo implode ( ', ', $result);
    echo "<br>";
?>
```

**Here is where I would like to include the company name**

```
Company Name:<input type="text" name="coname" value="<?php $result[a_aif.company_name_per_sedar];?>"><br>
```

and the rest of the form...

```
Year-End:<input type="date" name="year-end"><br>
Auditor:<input list="auditor" name="auditor"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you only missed `echo`

```
<input type="text" name="coname" value="<?php echo $result['a_aif.company_name_per_sedar'];?>">
```

Comment: what you get in `var_dump($result)` ?

Comment: shoot, now I get an error, and the variables don't pass.. error message is "Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/theaudit/public_html/_sandbox/data_entry_form.php on line 23"

Comment: paste the result of `var_dump($result)`

Comment: honestly, I don't even know how to get the var_dump($result)

Comment: Just `$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);var_dump($result);exit();` and run your php file

Comment: This is the result I get... bool(false). but that is because there was no $id (I think)

Comment: This means your query returns nothing

Comment: I have been able to make it work again, the issue was with the JavaScript... I can't seem to get the .data() working and instead I am using the .attr(). Now back to my original question, how can I use these results which are passing successfully..., in the HTML? I added "echo" but that didn't work...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22261/discussion-between-ben-jones-and-gbd)